# A basic tour on infinite dimensional manifolds

Tags: functional-analysis, manifolds, lie-groups, infinity

I have been doing some searching on material on infinite dimensional manifolds, but I found nothing satisfying.

I am not a mathematician, I am a physicist, and I am familiar with manifold theory in finite dimensions.

I would apreaciate if someone can explain to me how does a chart look in an infinite dimensional manifold, what is the tangent space, dual metric, the Λ'ς, etc.

For instance, in a 4 dimensional manifold a chart (roughly speaking) is a collection of 4 numbers (x, y, z, w).

I do want to know (in the same roughly level, so that I can "fell" it first), how does a chart in an the infinite dimensional case looks like.

Thanks for bothering,

Kostas

Comment: As you are a physicist, then I’d presume you may also have a working knowledge of Hilbert space, so that might be good start. In this case the infinite dimensional “Hilbert manifold” is one that is locally a Hilbert space. Much carries over from the finite-dimensional case; you may consider the Wikipedia entry https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_manifold as a good start.

Comment: There are many different ways to generalize the notion of a manifold to infinite dimension, each with their own (often significant) complications and drawbacks. Roughly, these depend on which topological vector space serves as the "local model" for the charts. There have been [several reference request questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Breference-request%5D+infinite+dimensional+manifolds) on the topic.

Comment: @Jack LeGrüß  Can you prescribe me a chart in such a Hilbert manifold ?

Comment: kosta an jereis ellhnika steile na ta poume kai go me ta idia asxoloyme